# Подключение к базе данных. Когда создавать и сколько ему жить в веб-приложении?

Tags: база-данных, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, http, веб-программирование

Когда создавать подключение к базе данных?

1. На каждый запрос к базе
2. На каждый HTTP-запрос
3. Глобально в рамках домена - от старта приложения до его смерти

**Первые два** позволяют локализовать ошибки (обрыв связи с базой покрашит минимум запросов), обеспечит многопоточную обработку запросов к базе(?) на стороне веб-сервера.

**Третий** - сократит оверхед на подключениях, особенно если БД вынесена на отдельный сервер, но лишится плюсов первых двух.

Так что же лучше и в каких случаях стоит применять? Интересно это как по поводу чистого ADO.NET, так и EF (если под "подключением" мы будем понимать наследника DbContext). По поводу последнего в туториалах в интернете рассуждают о разнице между п.1 и п.2, но не п.3. Почему?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если у программиста возникает такой вопрос, то ему стоит использовать `Entity Framework`, по тому, что в данном случае фреймворк окажется умнее программиста, который своими попытками оптимизации с наибольшей вероятностью сделает только хуже.

Во первых, `DbContext`, это `Unit of Work`(как и `ISession` в `NHibernate`)

Наличие одного `DbContext` для всего приложения - плохая идея. Единственная ситуация, где это имеет смысл, когда у вас есть однопоточное приложение и база данных, которая используется исключительно этим экземпляром приложения. `DbContext` не поточно-безопасный, а так же DbContext кэширует данные, по этому вы быстро получите не актуальный кэш. Все это приведет к различным проблемам, когда несколько пользователей/приложений будут работать с этой базой данных одновременно. По этому если у вас не вышеописанная ситуация, то вам лучше инжектить `DbContext` в каждую задачу. Создавать же контекст на каждый запрос не лучший вариант с точки зрения производительности. Во первых при подключении происходит аутентификация и авторизация, во вторых вы теряете преимущества благодаря кешированию.

Другими словами, вам нужно выделять `DbContext` на каждую бизнес-задачу.

Comment: А по сути можете сказать? Или по той же причине EF используете?)

Comment: @free_ze добавил вам ответ по сути.

Comment: С EF-контекстом ясненько, спасибо. Кстати, в хибернейте сессионные объекты вроде из фабрики берутся, какая магия состояний кроется за ней - я не знаю. Тогда что насчет коннекшена в обычном ADO.NET? Так сказать, если копнуть до самых низов, подключение к базе каждый раз устанавливать лучше или одно на всех? Для веб-приложения, с многопоточным доступом и с соблюдением синхронизации, конечно.

Comment: Одна задача - одно подключение. И не важно, чем вы там пользуетесь.